# change groupby dimension to 1 from 2 in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I performed a groupby:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'grp':['a','a','b','b'],'value':[1,2,1,10]})

df.groupby('grp').agg({'value':['mean','median']})
```

and got:

[image]

how do I change this to a normal df that I can manipulate and access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code a bit - add column for aggregation after `groupby` and pass list of functions:

```
df1 = df.groupby('grp')['value'].agg(['mean','median'])
print (df1)
     mean  median
grp              
a     1.5     1.5
b     5.5     5.5
```

---

Another idea is remove first level of `MultiIndex`, but if more columns is possible get duplicated columns names:

```
df1 = df.groupby('grp').agg({'value':['mean','median']})

df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)
print (df1)

     mean  median
grp              
a     1.5     1.5
b     5.5     5.5
```

Then is better for avoid duplicated columns names use `map` with `join`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('grp').agg({'value':['mean','median']})

df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df1)
     value_mean  value_median
grp                          
a           1.5           1.5
b           5.5           5.5
```

Or for pandas 0.25 use [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling):

```
df2 = df.groupby("grp").agg(a=pd.NamedAgg(column='value', aggfunc='mean'),
                            b=pd.NamedAgg(column='value', aggfunc='median'))

print (df2)

       a    b
grp          
a    1.5  1.5
b    5.5  5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply drop a level of the columns and reset the index of the `DataFrame` like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'grp':['a','a','b','b'],'value':[1,2,1,10]})

df1 = df.groupby('grp').agg({'value':['mean','median']})
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)
df1.reset_index()
```

Also, if you want a combined column, you can:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
```

instead of:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Comment: what is different like my answer?

Comment: @jezrael you don't use the reset_index() function.